# VLAN ingress filtering - understanding correctly and verify its functionality?

Tags: security, vlan, switch

When I tag traffic wrongly on a port (to do VLAN hopping like an potential attacker) should I be able to see ingress traffic to this VLAN on the port - like by mirorring the port in question when VLAN ingress filtering is disabled on a managed switch?

Longer explanation:
I've been told for Netgear and Allied Telesis gear that by default vlan ingress filtering is not enabled and that VLAN memberships only apply to egress traffic. Thus I'd epect that an ingress VLAN 100 tagged packet on a port not member on VLAN 100 would be accepted ingress, but no answer would be received by the sender (like icmp echo reply) due to vlan membership's egress filtering behaviour).

I've been doing some lab work and wanted to be certain how this features really works.
maybe someone can can enlighten me?

Comment: Thanks, the strange thing is that my attacker client (maybe configured wrongly?) was sending ingress ping on VLAN 100 but I wasn't able to see this ingress traffic by using port mirroring. (I'd have expected to not see egress icmp echo replies). So at least I seem to have understood the concept, demonstrating it in real-life seems to be tougher though ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah, the gap been theory and reality often dwarfs the grand canyon ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything fundamentally wrong with your assumptions, there is a single list for each VLAN, including the ports which are enabled, and whether the traffic is to be tagged or untagged. Egress filtering is the basis on which the VLAN separation functions, not allowing ports to transmit traffic they are not responsible for.

Netgear defines ingress filtering as :

`Ingress Filtering - When enabled, the frame is discarded if this port is not a member of the VLAN with which this frame is associated. In a tagged frame, the VLAN is identified by the VLAN ID in the tag. In an untagged frame, the VLAN is the Port VLAN ID specified for the port that received this frame. When disabled, all frames are forwarded in accordance with the 802.1Q VLAN bridge specification.`

So it seems your assumption is correct, it will accept the traffic and forward it to other members in that group, but return traffic will be filtered out by the egress filter.